# Can't determine type for tag "<macro name='m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape'>?attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>" errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compiler-errors, version-conflict-engine-exception

I am in trouble having my android project. I have migrated my project into androidx. Then I faced much more errors. Some have been solved and some are still now. Now I face the following errors...

```
Error: Can't determine type for tag '<macro name="m3_comp_assist_chip_container_shape">? 
attr/shapeAppearanceCornerSmall</macro>'
```

here is the gradle.build(app) file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 33
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sevenringscement.smart.android"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 44
    versionName "4.4.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags ""
        }
    }
}
buildTypes {
   release {
       minifyEnabled false
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguardrules.pro'
       }
  }
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}

signingConfigs {
    release {
        v2SigningEnabled true
     }
  }

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'

// implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'

//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'

implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'

implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'

//Butter Knife
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'

//searchableSpinner
implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
// Check for v11.4.2 or higher
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'

// Add dependency
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
//implementation 'com.nbsp:materialfilepicker:1.9.1'

implementation 'com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.2.1'
```

}
Here is the build.gradle(Smart_app)..

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub projects/modules.

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    // Add dependency
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'
    //classpath 'com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.2.3'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they 
  belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}
 allprojects {
  repositories {
     // maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
     google()
     jcenter()
     maven {
         url 'https://maven.google.com/'
     }
   }
}
```

I have tried much more updating version of differents dependencies.
Android studio version is Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1. I
But I couldn't get any result. How to solve this?